# Maven exec:java goal is not running after test failures

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 maven goals

1) Clean Install
2) exec:java

When ever I ran the goal "mvn clean install", It is getting executed and after It triggers the exec:java goal directly, if the build got success. but If maven build fails, it is not triggering the "exec:java" job. I want to run the java job irrespective of any results.

## My POM:

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
             <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            <!-- <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${TestSuiteName}</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables> -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>         
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>send-report</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.acxsys.ocp.api.emt.ks.report.KSSendEmail</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your job with `mvn -fn clean install`

`-fn` means *fail-never* and this will always continue the goal(s) execution.

Comment: Still it is not executing the Maven java goal.